# How do I get to the objective in chapter 12?

Tags: hotline-miami

I have reached chapter 12 "Trauma" in Hotline Miami, which is in the hospital. I believe this is the stealth level that has been mentioned by various reviews.

I can see what I think is the objective of the level in the top left corner of the map:

[image]

I've managed to sneak to the door that is visible on the right hand side of the screenshot, however, the door appears to be broken or locked, so I can't get across the corridor.

How do I progress from here? Or am I taking the wrong approach for this level?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are in fact multiple ways to complete this section of the level. The actual goal is to reach the lift on the far right hand side.

The first way is to grab the keycard, as mentioned in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94457/how-do-i-get-to-the-objective-in-chapter-12/94487#94487), which opens the locked door directly opposite, allowing you to proceed. This route is marked in red on the screenshot below.

The second way is to head down the corridor directly to the lift, being careful to avoid being spotted by the wandering nurses/doctors. This route is marked in orange on the screenshot below.

[image]

If you're having difficulty on this level, one thing to note that might help, is that the cops only notice you when they're not reading; so make sure you only go into their line of sight when their newspapers are up (I completely failed to notice this the first time I tried this level).

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to grab the keycard to gain access to the room in the top right. The keycard can be seen in the screenshot above, it's in the bottom left room (I think this is the room above the one you start in) and has a red arrow pointing to it.

I had the exact same problem when I was on chapter 12. It took me a good five minutes before I spotted the keycard and realised what I had to do.